# Combining definitions with id to print and find the number of repetitions

Tags: javascript, graph, localhost, amcharts

I have two localhost addresses. One has an ID field and the other has a definition field. I combined the ID numbers with the definition, but now I want to calculate the number of repetitions of each activity. I will draw a graph based on the number of repetitions of each activity. I think my code has an error in the if cycle, but I do not know what it is. How can ı fix my code?

Thank you.

```
<script>
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/activity",


    function (data, status) {
        var ActivityList = {};
        var Licenseactivity= [];

        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            ActivityList[item.id] = item.definition;
        });

        console.log(ActivityList)

        $.get("http://localhost:8080/license",


            function (data, status) {


                if (Licenseactivity[ActivityList[data.faalitetId]] == null) {
                    Licenseactivity[ActivityList[data.faalitetId]] = 0;
                }
                Licenseactivity[ActivityList[data.faalitetId]]++;
                console.log([ActivityList[data.faalitetId]]);

                $.each(ActivityList, function (index, item) {
                    newitem = {}
                    newitem["license"] = index;
                    newitem["numberofrecord"] = item;
                    Licenseactivity.push(newitem);
                });
                console.log(Licenseactivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

what I understand is in your get activity response you get the array of items where itemId can be repeated 
then u can add a counter against each ID with some prefix.

like

```
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        ActivityList[item.definition] = !ActivityList[item.definition]?
                                            1 : ActivityList[item.definition] + 1;
    });
```

Comment: It not working. Activity: Number of Records. I need to get a json format like this.

Comment: so why u put the definition in there put the count

Comment: //ActivityList[item.id] = item.definition;

Comment: ActivityList[item.id] = !!ActivityList[item.id]?
                                            1 : ActivityList[item.id] + 1;

Comment: I think I can count only definition without ID numbers.

Comment: ActivityList[item. definition] = !ActivityList[item. definition]? 1 : ActivityList[item. definition] + 1;

Comment: var ActivityList = {};
        var Licenseactivity= [];

        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            ActivityList[item.id] = item.definition;/ ActivityList[item. definition] = !ActivityList[item. definition]? 1 : ActivityList[item. definition] + 1  Something wrong?

Comment: not count. I do not understand. Can you add fixed code?. Maybe  I do something wrong

Comment: dont no what to fix. what count u r getting?

Comment: Only the whole record was repeated. The code could not get the number of records.

Comment: can paste some json

Comment: try 


ActivityList[item. definition] = ActivityList.hasOwnProperty(item. definition) ? 1 : ActivityList[item. definition] + 1;

Comment: ActivityList[item. definition] = !ActivityList.hasOwnProperty(item. definition) ? 1 : ActivityList[item. definition] + 1;

Comment: paste some part of json u get in ActivityList

Comment: 9089:"ELEKTRİK MALZEMELERİ SATIŞ YERİ  " . So it not count. Only Id and Activity Name

Comment: {license: "9085", numberofrecord: "ANAHTARCI"} . And this is Licenseactivity variable.

Comment: Okey now it better but my ActivityList like that:{ruhsat: "AYAKKABI VE TERLİK İMALATI", sayi: 1}
101
:
{ruhsat: "ŞARKÜTERİ", sayi: 1}
102
:
{ruhsat: "DENİZ MAHSÜLLERİ SATIŞ YERİ  ", sayi: 1}

Comment: So it not count only write 1

Comment: Need to add ! sign in the condition

Comment: Always write that 1.

Comment: can paste ur code again let me check .. add in ur question, so it will more easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Only try count the definition. I dont need ID numbers.

$.get("http://localhost:8080/activity",

```
function (data, status) {
    var ActivityList = {};
    var Licenseactivity= [];

    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        ActivityList[item. definition] = !ActivityList.hasOwnProperty
        (item. definition) ? 1 : ActivityList[item. definition] + 1;

    });

    console.log(ActivityList)


        function (data, status) {


            if (Licenseactivity[ActivityList[data.faalitetId]] == null) {
                Licenseactivity[ActivityList[data.faalitetId]] = 0;
            }
            Licenseactivity[ActivityList[data.faalitetId]]++;
            console.log([ActivityList[data.faalitetId]]);

            $.each(ActivityList, function (index, item) {
                newitem = {}
                newitem["license"] = index;
                newitem["numberofrecord"] = item;
                Licenseactivity.push(newitem);
            });
            console.log(Licenseactivity);
```

Comment: can u also add ur console output  console.log(ActivityList)

Comment: AKTAR
:
321
ALÜMİNYUM DOĞRAMA ATÖLYESİ
:
321
ALÜMİNYUM DÖKÜM ATÖLYESİ
:
321
AMBALAJ ATIĞI GERİ DÖNÜŞÜM TESİSİ
:
321
AMBALAJ MALZEMELERİ SATIŞI
:
321
AMBALAJ MALZEMELERİ VE KOLİ İMALATI
:
321
ANAHTARCI
:

Comment: I have 320 activities and in activityList variable all activities have 321 records

Comment: Yes ı solve it with this code: if (typeof (licenseactivity[licensename]) == "undefined")licenseactivity[licensename] = 0; licenseactivity[licensename]+=1;

Answer (score 0):

The problem was corrected by adding the following lines of code.

```
 function (data, status) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                var licensename = ActivityList[item.gli1faliyetIsyeri];
                if (typeof (Licenseactivity[licensename]) == "undefined")
                Licenseactivity[licensename] = 0;
               Licenseactivity[licensename]+=1;
```